# How do i send tags with an aws api gateway request

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am trying to control access to my api gateway rest api with iam and to restrict access to some of the data via a get request using tags so i have a policy like this:

```
  Version: "2012-10-17"
  Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - execute-api:Invoke
      Resource:
        - Fn::Join:
          - "/"
          - 
           - Fn::Join: [":", ["arn:aws:execute-api", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, {"Ref":"AWS::AccountId"}, {"Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi"}]]
            - ${self:custom.stage}
            - GET
            - items*
      Condition: 
        ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals: 
          aws:RequestTag/businessStream:
            - CI
```

And i have scoured the docs but cannot see see how i am supposed to add the 'businessStream' tag to my request to get it to allow my request.

Is it supposed to be a header tag? or some other means? What format should this take in my request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags in various ways to provide access control. The `requestTag` however is mainly used in api calls in which tags are actually set or removed (e.g. tag-resource-like api's). From the docs:

> Availability – This key is included in the request context when tags are passed in the request. When multiple tags are passed in the request, there is one context key for each tag key-value pair.

Depending on your use case, maybe the `aws:PrincipalTag` condition works better, since it looks for any tags attachted to the role or iam user making the request.  If you want to get very fancy you can even add sessionTags (tags that only last for the session for a certain principal), but this is less common.

Comment: Thanks for the info, what we are trying to do is use the policy i mentioned ina user group to control access for users and i was hoping the requestTag could be added to a request via a header or something to validate against the user/user group making the request to control the access. 
How do you add the the tags to a request? is it as i hoped and via the headers?

Comment: Tag the users themselves and use the `aws:PrincipalTag` condition as mentioned in the post.